# Azure WebJob Output Multiple Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have built an Azure Webjob that takes a queue trigger and an blob reference as input, processes the file and creates multiple output blob files (it's breaking a PDF into individual pages).  In order to output the multiple blobs, I have code in the job that explicitly creates the storage/container connection and does the output.  It would be cleaner to let webjobs handle this if it's possible using attributes.

Is there a way to output multiple blobs to a container?  I can output multiple queue messages using the QueueAttribute and an ICollector, but I don't see if that's possible with a Blob (like a container reference where I can send multiple blobs).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct - BlobAttribute does not support an ICollector binding. In the current beta release, we have added some new bindings that might help you a bit. For example, you can now bind to a **CloudBlobContainer** and you could use that to create additional blobs. See the [release notes](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Release-Notes) for more details.

Another possibility would be for you to use the **IBinder** binding ([example here](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/QueueOperations/Functions.cs#L32)). It allows you to imperatively bind to a blob. You could do that multiple times in your function.

Comment: The CloudBlobContainer looks like a good solution when out of beta.  For now, with IBinder, just to extend the example to my situation, does this look correct to bind a MemorySteam:  

`MemoryStream pdfPage = binder.Bind<MemoryStream>(new BlobAttribute("page/" + page.id + ".pdf"));
myPdfLib.SaveAsSteam(pdfPage);`

Comment: Yes that looks right. You can use the **1.1.0-beta1** release now from nuget if you wish (unless you're saying you don't want to use pre-release packages). We should be out of beta very soon.